# Насколько соответствуют системе русского языка глаголы совершенного вида "впечатлить - впечатлиться", а также причастие "впечатлен"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, аспектология

Мне эти глаголы режут ухо (в отличие от формы несовершенного вида "впечатлять"). Нет ли здесь скрытого иноязычного воздействия?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, иноязычное влияние есть (веет английским глаголом to impress). До распространения через СМИ формы впечатлить/впечатлять (Ушаков приводил её как "книжн." со ссылкой на ранний прецедент из отзыва о фильме в газете "Правда": "... фильма не впечатлила...") употреблялось выражение с глаголом "произвести впечатление на..." Мне тоже не нравятся эти глаголы и (особенно) кр. страдательное причастие "впечатлён" (будто кого-то во что-то впечатали или вляпали) - я без них обхожусь. В классической русской литературе трудно их встретить, хотя кто-то находил их в мемуарах одного из князей (вероятно, автор знал языки и сам образовал такое упрощение). Употреблять или нет - вопрос литературного стиля; просторечием это сейчас уже не назвать (к сожалению).

Comment: Думаю, активность этих глаголов в современной массовой речи связана с экспансией английского языка в последние три десятилетия. Интересно было бы рассмотреть это слово в аспекте семантического калькирования. Для  этого нужны контексты и сопоставительный анализ русских и английских источников.. В настоящее время ряд исследований, посвященных семантическому калькированию в прошлые периоды развития  русского языка, но текущие актуальные процессы как-то остаются вне внимания исследователей...